# wheel does not turn when pedaling on mongoose motivator

Tags: rear-wheel

on a Mongoose Motivator, when I spin the pedals the wheel does not engage. I removed the chain and lubricated it but it still does not work.

Comment: Does the cassette turn?

Comment: If the chain is properly installed and the rear cog is turning with the chain then something has come apart inside the rear hub.  You need to take it to a bike shop.

Comment: From a quick Google, the Mongoose Motivator appears to be a BMX bike.  If the back gears are spinning but the wheel isn't moving, then there's probably a problem with the freewheel. Perhaps the pawls are stuck.

Comment: The pawls might also be worn or powdered. Does the freewheel make the typical ratcheting sound if you spin the wheel?

Answer (score 4):

The pawls in the rear wheel's freehub are not engaging.

Your options are to replace the freehub, or the entire rear wheel.

It is possible to get more life out of a freehub by disassembling and either replacing broken springs, or grinding a sharper corner on the lip if its rounded over.  Sometimes its a matter of congealed grease stopping the engagement, and a clean+lube can fix that up.

The temporary roadside fix can involve wiring the cassette directly to the spokes, or simply hitting the hub until a pawl engages.  Once you have drive, do not coast at all because it likely won't reengage.